# Re run previous command with different arguments

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, keyboard-shortcuts

If you want to re run a command with the same arguments you can do something like this:

```
vim long_filename
cat !$                     #same as 'cat long_filename'
```

This saves having to type out the previous argument again when it is passed to `cat`.

However, how would I pass arguments that are **not the same** to the **last run** script/command?

```
long_annoying_script_name arg1 arg2
? arg3 arg4                                  #? signifies shortcut symbols such as '!$'
```

Of course I could just press the 'up' arrow and delete the arguments and type the new ones, but is there a shorter/faster way?

I DO NOT want to assign an alias.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`!:0` should do the trick. From the zsh documentation:

```
   Word Designators
       A word designator indicates which word or words of a given command line
       are to be included in a history reference.  A `:' usually separates the
       event specification from the word designator.  It may be  omitted  only
       if  the  word designator begins with a `^', `$', `*', `-' or `%'.  Word
       designators include:

       0      The first input word (command).
       n      The nth argument.
       ^      The first argument.  That is, 1.
       $      The last argument.
       %      The word matched by (the most recent) ?str search.
       x-y    A range of words; x defaults to 0.
       *      All the arguments, or a null value if there are none.
       x*     Abbreviates `x-$'.
       x-     Like `x*' but omitting word $.
```

(It works with bash, too.) There’s also `!-1` if you find that more convenient to type.

Comment: +1 - a shortcut for `!!:0 arg3 arg4`
documentation: [Bash History word designators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html#Word-Designators)

Comment: @hdl: What would you want it to do in a script – refer to other parts of the script, or to the user’s history?

Comment: From the user's history. I used `fc -ln -1` to get the previous command line from history, but then I had to parse it into a single command word, then single subcommand (for `git`), then args, before I could actually run it. Maybe there are some simpler solutions...

Answer (score 15):

#TL;DR
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: inserts last command without the arguments

---

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 with the default keybinding settings *(i.e Emacs keybindings)*

---

## You can combine keyboard shortcuts

Let's consider the last command to be:

```
mv foo bar
```

<kbd>up</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>: last command without the last word = `mv foo`

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: first argument of last command = `mv`

### Some useful shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: insert last argument from last command *(repeat to go back in history)*
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>number</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: insert #nth last argument from last command *(repeat to go back in history)*
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> , <kbd>number</kbd> , <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, **zsh:** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>: insert #nth first argument from last command *(repeat to go back in history)*
- **Cut commands** (relative to cursor's position)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>: cuts last word
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>: cuts next word
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>: cuts everything after
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, **zsh:** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>: cuts everything before
- **zsh:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>: cuts the entire command *(In bash you can combine <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>)*
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>: paste characters previously cut with any **Cut command**. *In bash You can chain **cut commands**, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> will paste them all.*
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>: undo last edit *(very useful when exceeding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>)*
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>: move to last word
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>: move to next word
- <kbd>home</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>: move to start of command
- <kbd>end</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>: move to end of command

#### To see all shortcuts available

- **bash:** `bind -lp`
- **zsh:** `bindkey -L`

### Unfortunately there are some limitations

"words" only includes `a-zA-Z` characters, so any symbol character will stop word-shortcuts.

So if last argument was a url and you want to erase it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> it will be a pain.

E.g: `curl -I --header "Connection: Keep-Alive" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176514/re-run-previous-command-with-different-arguments`

To erase that **url** using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, you'd have to repeat it 12 times.

---

It would be great to have similar shortcuts that only stops at the **space character**

---

I'm keeping this up-to-date here: https://github.com/madacol/docs/blob/master/bash-zsh_TerminalShorcuts.md

Comment: This answer presumes emacs keybindings.

Comment: @WilliamPursell What does it mean?. Any example where I wouldn't presume it?
I've only tested this on Ubuntu, with bash and zsh

Comment: emacs key bindings are the default setting. However, if you change to vi key bindings (in bash, with `set -o vi`, or by modifying ~/.inputrc), the keystrokes are completely different.